# Retrieve a value by Javascript Regular

Tags: javascript, html, get, regular-language

I have :

```
<script>
var s="/xyz/abc/5-6-12-0-0-1-0";
document.write(s.match(/((\d+)$)/g));
</script>
```

I've tried everything I know but I can not figure out how to get reasonable results "1". It is always the last number 0

I need to get the value "1" by regular.

This demo : http://jsfiddle.net/51ezkxaq/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/51ezkxaq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can positive look ahead assertion for finding the digit before the last

```js
var s = "/xyz/abc/5-1-12-0-0-1-0";
document.write(s.match(/(\d+)(?=-\d+$)/));
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/xB6fZ2/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @LêTùng : glad to help :)